# Tree structure for namespace package

Tags: python, networkx, namespace-package

I have an package named `networkx-metis` which has the following tree structure

```
networkx-metis/
              setup.py
              networkx/
                      __init__.py
                      addons/
                            __init__.py
                            metis/
                                 metis.py
```

`networkx.addons.metis` is supposed to be installed as a namespace package in [networkx](https://github.com/networkx/networkx) core package. The two `__init__.py` above contains the single line of code

```
__import__('pkg_resources').declare_namespace(__name__)
```

Now I have some specific questions,

- What should be the changes in the `networkx` core package? Where should I put empty `__init__.py` files?
- What should be the value of `namespace_packages` in `setup()` of the `setup.py` of `networkx-metis`?

Comment: There are some examples of namespace packages for Python. Didn't that help?

Comment: Sorry, but no. They are simple `package.module` and `package.addon` examples. This seems to be more complicated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What should be the changes in the networkx core package? Where should I put empty `__init__.py` files?

Add a `__init__.py` inside `networkx/addons/` with the single line of code in it

```
__import__('pkg_resources').declare_namespace(__name__)
```

> What should be the value of namespace_packages in setup() of the setup.py of networkx-metis?

It should be

```
namespace_packages = ['networkx.addons', 'networkx']
```